# Constructor error '...cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

Why I can't use a student constructor? It gives me an error "***Timetable()' in ''Student()' in 'com.elinext.university.entity.Student' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'***", if I delete lombok annotation with NoArgsConstructor I doesn't have errors in service, but I get them in entity class. Error in test method in line *Student actual = new Student("Nick", "Lobanovsky");*. When I do a constructor with firstName and lastName without lombok it works fine.

**entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long studentId;

    @Column(
            name = "first_name",
            nullable = false
    )
    @NonNull private String firstName;

    @Column(
            name = "last_name",
            nullable = false
    )
    @NonNull private String lastName;
```

**test**

```
@SpringBootTest
class UniversityApplicationTests {
    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;
    private final TimetableRepository timetableRepository;
    private final GroupsRepository groupsRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UniversityApplicationTests(
            StudentRepository studentRepository,
            TimetableRepository timetableRepository,
            GroupsRepository groupsRepository){

        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
        this.timetableRepository = timetableRepository;
        this.groupsRepository = groupsRepository;
    }

    @Test
    public void getStudent(){
        Student expected = studentRepository.findByStudentId(1L).orElse(null);
        Student actual = new Student("Nick", "Lobanovsky");
        
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected.getFirstName(), actual.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

**repository**

```
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {
    Optional<Student> findByStudentId(Long studentId);
}
```

Comment: are you trying to parse something into timetable Entity ?
And how are you parsing it

Comment: I need to write tests that will add entities to tables, arguments of "addStudent" I would get from test

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with the `Student`constructor when the error message doesn't mention it? Please post a [mre].

Comment: It's actually difficult understanding what you want to do

Comment: If that is your actual, real code, then it's all the more puzzling, because your `Student` entity does not reference the `TimeTable` entity, yet the error says that the (lombok-generated, from what I can see) constructor of the former uses the latter.